# standalone python script unable to execute merge vector layers

Tags: pyqgis, merge

I am trying to run the qgis merge vector layers tool in a standalone script however I am getting the following error:

```
Unable to execute algorithm
Wrong parameter value:/Users/jt/workspace/Manna/workflow/mesh.shp;/Users/jt/workspace/Manna/utm/CW_roads_clean.shp
```

I first ran the tool normally and then copied the code out of the history. I have also successfully ran the code in the qgis python console. It is just when I try to run it in the following stand alone script that it has issues.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/plugins')

from qgis.core import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import processing
from processing.core.Processing import Processing

app = QApplication([])
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/usr", True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()
Processing.initialize()
Processing.updateAlgsList()

processing.runalg("qgis:mergevectorlayers",
    "/Users/jt/workspace/Manna/workflow/mesh.shp;/Users/jt/workspace/Manna/utm/CW_roads_clean.shp",
    "/Users/jt/workspace/Manna/ten_meter/temp_merge.shp")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem ended up not being with running the algorithm but instead the layers were not valid. I had the wrong prefix path; it should have been:
`QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS", True)`

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
layer_merge= processing.runalg('qgis:mergevectorlayers', '/Users/jt/workspace/Manna/workflow/mesh.shp','/Users/jt/workspace/Manna/utm/CW_roads_clean.shp', None)
processing.runandload("qgis:dissolve", layer_merge['OUTPUT'], True, '', "/Users/jt/workspace/Manna/ten_meter/temp_merge.shp")
```

Comment: The first line gives an error:
Error: Wrong number of parameters

I also tried it combining the two input files separating them with a semicolon but that gave me the same error as my original code.